# PHP detect closures

Tags: php, closures, rtti

If I run this:

```
$> php -r 'print gettype (function () {});'
```

I get the output

```
object
```

The argument to `gettype` is a closure, "object" isn't specific enough. How do I detect whether an arbitrary variable is a closure or not?

(The end-goal is to recursively reach every closure in a tree made of Arrays.)

Comment: `callable`, `is_callable`, `instanceof Closure`

Comment: why the down vote? it seems to me as a real, on-topic question

Comment: Like @Gordon, you could use get_class($var_func); It returns Closure.

Comment: @SinistraD shows no research effort

Comment: @Gordon yeah, I thought that was the reason, just asked to be sure, you should note that within your comment, helps the op improve, also blocks these kinds of questions getting high votes just because of sympathy